# Creating an image with a transparent background in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

how can you make a new image with a transparent background?

```
convert -size 120x22 gfx/gen/tmp.png
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this:

```
convert -size 122x22 xc:none gfx/gen/tmp.png
```

Comment: Is there a way to create a semi-transparent one? I tried the rgba setting, but it always created a solid colour. `gm convert -size 100x100 xc:rgba\(255,255,255,0.5\) canvas.png`.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I can only link the reference, there are several ways to define alpha values: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#color_semitrans

Comment: Cool, the hex version worked, however GraphicsMagick works like the old ImageMagick. But the rgba style doesn't work in GraphicsMagick.